# java send push notification to mobile browser

Tags: java, web, notifications

I have a lot of confusion about (web) push notifications ..

I've read several articles on google, about web push notification and saw sono java libraries with examples (mobile browser notification cannot be showed if the browser is not active..), but I can't find an article/example that fully explains the situation ..

I should develop a web app (responsive website, NO mobile native APP) with java tecnology (jsp, xhtml, primefaces..), to be viewed mainly on mobile devices (mobile browser), and I need primarily to show notifications to the user .. i think that the web app should be develop in javascript (not only java)

the problem is.. how do I implement these (web) notifications?

thank you for a clear explanation!

Comment: For example websockets of google cloud messaging

Comment: without creating a native APP?

Comment: Yes, just a webapp